# Help with this exercise: $\lim_{x \to \ 0} \frac{\cos2x}{\sin3x} $

Tags: calculus, limits

Help with this exercise:

$$\lim_{x \to \ 0} \frac{\cos2x}{\sin3x} $$

I know that is $\infty $. But How??

Comment: What is the function *sen*?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos 2x}{3x}\cdot\frac{3x}{\text{sen}\ 3x} = \cdots$$

Comment: @Bernard $\operatorname{sen} = $Seno $= \sin$, in spanish.

Comment: I thought the name `sin` in formulae was international.

Answer (score 2):

You will have a problem with the existence of this limit. We have $$\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(2x) =1,$$ $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sin(3x) =0^+, \quad \lim_{x\to 0^-} \sin(3x) =0^-.$$ Hence $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(3x)}= +\infty, \quad \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(3x)}= -\infty.$$ Since the right and the left limits are different, the limit at $0$ doesn't exist.